# querySelector method obsoleted?

Tags: javascript, selector, selectors-api

I'm currently learning the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method and was surprised to find that it was classified as obsolete

[image]

Here is the link to the [screenshot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Is `querySelector` method really has been obsoleted? If yes, what is the reason? And what method should be used instead?

Comment: I think the Sepcs is obsolete not the method itself.

Comment: I think that's just incomplete documentation on that page. Here's the page for `Element.querySelector` and it does link to the latest spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: @Tushar, its it possible to obsolete the Specification but part of what is defined by the specification is still valid?

Comment: It looks like the newer spec is here: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-queryselector

Comment: @Nisarg, ah ok, i see. Its a bit strange that documentation for a method exist in two places. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: web development sure is confusing lol soldier on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `querySelector` is not obsolete. Obsolete methods are generally highlighted on MDN with a warning like this:

[image]

<sup>You can see an example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement</sup>

---

It looks like the list of specifications hasn't been updated on [that page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). However if you look at the specs on the page for [`Element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), you can find a link to the spec here: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-queryselector

Comment: Ah I now see, so the biggest thing is that there is only a single method, attached to ParentNode, be it an Element or an *NonElementParentNode* (i.e Document). So what should happen on MDN is actually to obsolete these two pages in favor of `/ParentNode/querySelector/`, weird it's not there yet when we see they have [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll)